# Guessing game where computer generates random number

Tags: c++

I am implementing a Guessing game where computer generates random number with the following code:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (true){
        int num = rand() % 10, guess, tries = 0;        

        while (true){
            cout << "Enter number 1 to 10:";
            cin >> guess;

            if (tries > 2)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (guess > num)
            {
                cout << "Too High ! Try again"<<endl;

            }

            if (guess > 10)
            {
                cout << "Error ReEnter 1 to 10\n";
            }
            else if (guess < num)
            {
                cout << "Too Low! Try again"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            tries++;            
        }

        if (tries > 2)          
        {
            cout <<"\nYou ran out of tries!\n";
            cout << "\nThe answer is:" << num << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nCONGRATZ!! You guess correctly!\n";
        }       
        return 0;
    }
}
```

One of the problems is: yet when user attempt 3 times, the program shows "ran out of tries" even though the user input is correct on 3rd try.

### Questions:

1.How do I inform user that their input exceeds 10 and show an error message to user to enter values from 1 to 10 ?

2.How to correct the aforementioned problem?

Comment: well, how about change it to `if (tries > 3)` ?

Comment: i edited it to 3, but this statement just add the number of tries

Comment: Given `rand() % 10`, the answer will never be 10.

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing the program for you here is some pseudo code.

```
get a random number rand()%10+1  1..10 call it R
loop
  get user input N
  if N == R then show OK and break loop
  if N < R show too low 
  else show too high
  increment tries
  if tries == 3 then break loop
end loop
```

Comment: plus one from me, I guess I'm following the _"teaching by example"_ :)

Comment: thanks. i also thought it better to give a hint than write the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `if else` conditions that make your code unnecessarily complex, to answer your second question specifically the unwanted behaviour is caused from the:

```
  if (tries > 2)
  {
      break;
  }
```

which exits the loop regardless of the guess, as it is dependant only on the number of tries. Regarding your first question, I decided to provide you with more simple implementation that includes an answer to it as well.

You could replace your `while` loop with a `do-while` loop, terminated when the random number is guessed, i.e.:

```
int main(){
    // initialize random seed
    srand (time(NULL));
    // generate a random number within [1,10]
    int secretRandom = rand() % 10 + 1;
    // initialize 
    int yourGuess = 11;

    // input loop
    string promptMessage = "Type a a number from 1 to 10."
    do{
        cout << promptMessage << '\n';
        // read input
        cin >> yourGuess >> endl;
        // guessed number relatively to the randomly generated  
        if (secretRandom < yourGuess) cout << "The secret number is lower\n";
        else if (secretRandom > yourGuess)  cout << "The secret number is higher\n";
    }while(yourGuess != secretRandom) 
    // if you guess the random number exit the loop and display success message
    cout << "You guessed right!\n";

return 0;
}
```

To reduce the amount of guesses to specific number you can enclose the `do-while` loop and the *success message* in a `for` loop, for example:

```
int numberOfGuesses = 3;
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfGuesses; ++i){
    //...
}
```

If you want to enforce the user to input a number in the range from 1 to 10, you could do it by:

```
int yourGuess = 11;
int lowerBound = 0;
int upperBound = 10;
do{
    cin >> yourGuess;
    // not type safe
}while(yourGuess < lowerBound || yourGuess > upperBound);
```